# Power BI - Ignore slicer but keep its selection

Tags: powerbi

I have created a slicer (slicer 1) that shows only my company's products, with the remaining grouped in "Others".

**Slicer 1**

- Product A
- Product B
- Others

Each Product is associated with a different Market. If I select one product it will automatically select a Market. Example: Product A filters for Market X; Product B filters for Market Y; so on.

I would like to have a table that shows all Product A competitors' in Market X.
I haven't been able to create a measure that ignores the selection in Slicer 1 (so it doesn't only show Product A, Product B, ... in the table) but keeps it associated market. I would like to have something like this:

### Selecting Product A in Slicer 1

**Market X Performance**

- Product A        Sales €€
- Competitor AA    Sales €€
- Competitor AB    Sales €€

### Selecting Product B in Slicer 1

**Market Y Performance**

- Product B        Sales €€
- Competitor BB    Sales €€
- Competitor BC    Sales €€

Any tips?

---

Many thanks,

AS

Answer (score 0):

i think this could be done, by edit slicers- and then sync slicers and you can choose which columns it will affect.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this option but this way it will not filter the Market and show the competitors only for that Market.